# AccessViolationException after upgrade to .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, access-violation

I upgrade a wpf desktop application from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0.(Changed the target framework to 4.0). After the upgrade it shows some unexpected behaviours.

There is a tab control in the application. when i click a particular tab only either one of the following behaviours occurs.
1. Application crashed
2. AccessViolationException "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
3. Application closed
4. Sometimes working fine.

Other than this tab control issue, application closed unexpectedly. (when closing a tab or scroll a window). Sometiems Fatalexecutionengine exception also thrown.

Everything worked fine before converted to .Net 4.0.

I don't have any clue what's happening there. Please help to resolve this.

Comment: One idea is that some of your p/invoke code has always been broken. But implementation details of the old framework masked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to manually delete all the assemblies then rebuild everything with the new framework ? Visual Studio is often like windows, it needs to redo everything lol

Comment: i tried but it did not work. besides we tried to build the solution using our CI server, the output also had the same issue.

Comment: does this tab control is very different from the others ? is there some databindings or complex dataset manipulation ? maybe there's a deprecated control or command that has an issue with something more recent in the new framework; try to comment all the code executed on the click event of this tab control so you can have something that doesn't crash, then uncomment until it crashes

Comment: You are correct. Earlier version of Icsharpcode.Texteditor caused all these issues. whenever text editor loaded inside the tab item as a first control application crashed or exception threw. But any other controls such as button loaded before this text editor it worked fine. Anyway Icsharpcode.Texteditor not supported the .net 4 target version. ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit is the WPF-based text editor that target .net 4.(it's the replacement for ICharpCode.Texteditor) anyway I tried the latest version of Icharpcode.Texteditor it solved my issues. Thank you for your assistance.